# Why is the ability to publish not available in VS 2017 on new surface pro

Tags: visual-studio-2017, windows-10, surface-pro

Just setup new surface pro. Moved from Laptop. I installed VS 2017 (even tried 2019) and loaded project from old laptop. Made changes and went to Publish new install and getting 'The publish components are not available. You need to reinstall Visual Studio to publish your application.' under publish tab. Program will build and can run the application from IDE.
Had to save project and publish using old laptop. I searched the internet and seen many posts about this issue but no solutions.
I have uninstalled VS 2017 and reinstalled. Have tried community version and pro version and same issue.

Hopefully someone has seen this and actually found a way to correct issue.

Comment: did you find any solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that my old laptop also had visual studio 2015 installed. I went ahead and installed that on new surface and now the ability to publish is available in vs 2017